# Etiquette for answering own question based on a comment

Tags: discussion, answers, comments, etiquette, comment-replies

Currently I have two questions on SO that are answered by a commenter rather than an answerer. In both cases the comment is in direct response to the question; neither of the questions have any answers on them at the moment.

What is the etiquette for marking the question as answered by answering it myself and referring to the answer in the comment?

The reason I am interested in doing this is so someone who searches and sees the question in their results will have a better indication that an answer is available.

Thanks!

Comment: Just post an answer of your own. The only requirement is that you give credit ([attribution](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing)) to the author of the comment. Simply saying, "As Chris Perry said in [a comment](https://example.com)..." is fine. Tip: You can get a link to a comment by clicking on its timestamp. (Don't do it here; I'm looking for a dupe. :-))

Comment: "I'm wondering what the etiquette is for marking the question as answered by answering it myself" - there is no feature on the site for marking a question as answered. You might be referring to the feature of flagging an answer as the one that helped you best - big difference. You can of course do that to your own answer, it has very little significance.